# Git patch series create and send using git send-email

Tags: linux, git, patch

I'm new to git and Linux. Now my problem is how to create a series of patches using git format-patch and how to send those patches to the respective maintainers using `git send-email`.

I just found that using this cmd `git format-patch -2 --thread -n --cover-letter` we can create a patch series with cover-letter for 2 patch.

So, After done with this cmd It'll create a cover-letter and we need to edit the cover letter right?
Once we done with creating a patch, How to send those patches to respective maintainers?

Till now I'm sending a single patch with `git send-email --cc-cmd='./scripts/get_maintainer.pl -norolestats patch_name.patch' patch_name.patch`
So, Is it like we need to send each individual patch using this cmd or any other ways are there?

Answer (score 1):

> So, Is it like we need to send each individual patch using this cmd

The [`git send-email` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) can take multiple argument.

You can refer to an article like "[Git: send patch using send-email & Gmail](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2019/08/git-send-patch-using-send-email-and-gmail.html)" from [Revath S Kumar](https://blog.revathskumar.com/p/about-me.html), using:

```
git send-email *.patch
```

That way, you send everything in one command.

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be most convenient:

```
git format-patch --cover-letter --output-directory patches
```

Because then I can use `patches` in order to send out the whole series
instead of naming each patch independently.

> So, After done with this cmd It'll create a cover-letter and we need
> to edit the cover letter right?

Yes. The body and the subject.

The body is marked with `*** BLURB HERE ***` and the subject with `*** SUBJECT HERE ***`.

Be careful with Unicode in the subject. I’ve had an email get rejected
over that.